# How do I post to Facebook user's friend's wall with publish_stream but NOT offline_access using an application access token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token

Documentation for publish_stream reads: "Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access."

So the workflow is thus:

1. FB.login() with publish_stream scope like so:

   ```
   FB.login(function (response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
           FB.api('/me/permissions', function (permissions) {
               if (permissions.data[0].publish_stream == 1) {
                   //user has now granted publish_stream to this application
               }
           });
       }
   }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
   ```
2. Use the C# Facebook SDK to post to this user's friend's wall using the application's access token.

   ```
   var client = new FacebookClient(FacebookAppId, FacebookAppSecret);

   // Build the wall post
   dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
   parameters.message = facebookDeliveryQueueItem.MessageBody; // user message

   // Post to the wall
   client.Post(facebookRecipientId + "/feed", parameters);
   ```

This returns:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

However! If I attempt to use this code to post to MY OWN wall, it works just fine.

If a user grants publish_stream to my application, I can then use the the APPLICATION access token (you get this by issuing a GET to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=APP_ID_HERE&client_secret=APP_SECRET_HERE) to post on that user's wall -- but NOT to that user's friend's wall.

So is the "and to the streams of the user's friends" part of the Facebook documentation a lie or am I doing it wrong? There is a ton of misinformation out there.

Comment: This one is strange. I was able to post to a friend's wall using that permission using the graph API explorer tool.  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer  Can you try there to see if it works there for you?

Comment: As bool.dev said, you need user access token and not the app_access_token.. I tried with graph api explorer and used post method to post into both my wall and my  friend's wall

Comment: @bool.dev Well that's my question -- is the documentation wrong in saying that I can use the application token to post on a user's friend's wall or is this just not how you would do it?

Comment: yeah, obviously people decline offline_access quite often, you can try and explain to them that you need offline_access for such and such reasons, anyway it's good practice to let your users know why you need certain permissions. Otherwise let's hope that someone has an answer. I had gone through your questions, and i thought some answers were acceptable, imho.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You should explicitly specify `access_token` before issuing request, if you omit it `access_token` of current user is used.</strike>

Add this before call to `client.Post`

```
parameters.access_token = FacebookAppId+"|"+FacebookAppSecret;
```

The documentation is correct (in this case). You can post on user's and his friends wall once user granted you `publish_stream` permission using application `access_token` (**without** need to ask for `offline_access`!) with respect of wall owner preferences. Some users set privacy settings to deny specific users/application or even anyone other to post content.

Ensure you can post on that specific friend (one you have issue with) wall using http://facebook.com **and** using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) tool (providing application `access_token` for sure).

Comment: var client = new FacebookClient(FacebookAppId, FacebookAppSecret) sets the access_token used for the post to exactly this already.

Comment: @DanielCoffman, you're right, I wasn't aware of behavior of c# SDK and assumed it behave in a manner like official SDK (which wash't the case), I've rewritten the answer, hope it'll help.

Comment: @JuicyScripter I've been trying to post a friend's wall using the app access token, using the path `friendId/feed`, but this results in a status update for my friend (from my app), not a post to my friend's wall from me (through my app).  Is there a different path that I'm supposed to be using?

Comment: @ColdHawaiian, while publishing posts to user's friend feed using application `access_token` you should pass user's id in `from` field, so the post will be owned by user and not application. If you will use user's `access_token` this can be omitted.

Comment: @JuicyScripter I tried that, but the message still shows up as a status update for the friend, not a post to the friend's wall for a user.  But thanks for the suggestion anyway :)